# What is wrong with my Prometheus yml

Tags: prometheus

I am looking for some assistance with setting up my prometheus.yml file for federation. I started by setting up Prometheus and Grafana on a single instance (jenkins.xxx.com). Once I had that I moved on to trying to federate. I updated the yml per the internet examples. I reviewed as many examples as I could find on the internet in an attempt to resolve this issue myself but am stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my prometheus.yml file:

---

```
global:

  scrape_interval: 15s

  external_labels:
      promserver: 'fire05'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'federate'

    honor_labels: true
    metrics_path: '/federate'

    params:
      'match[]':
        - '{job="prometheus"}'
        - '{__name__=~"^job:.*"}'

    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 'jenkins7.xxx.com:9090'
        - 'jenkins5.xxx.com:9090'
```

This returns the following error:

> ERRO[0000] Error loading config: couldn't load configuration
>   (-config.file=prometheus.yml): yaml: line 17: did not find expected
>   key  source="main.go:160"

I also commented out the `- '{job="prometheus"}'` which then produced the following error:

> ERRO[0000] Error loading config: couldn't load configuration
>   (-config.file=prometheus.yml): yaml: line 19: mapping values are not
>   allowed in this context  source="main.go:160"

Thanks

Comment: What version of Prometheus are you using? I tested this configuration and it was accepted by Prometheus 1.7.1

Comment: I am also using Prometheus 1.7.1

Comment: @ConorB thanks for verifying that the config worked for you. This led me to re-type the yml file. There must have been something invisibly imbedded in the file when I did a copy and paste. My yml file is now working. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. I suspect the culprit was extra whitespace copied over that would have led to failed yaml parsing. Glad it's working for you now!